# CRUDify MegaProtoUser - is this a correct solution?

Tags: scala, lift, crud

I am using liftweb 2.5-SNAPSHOT with Scala 2.9.1.

In my lift application I want to use a USer class with both, the MegaProtoUser trait for self administration for each user and the CRUDify trait for a CRUD view for the administrator.

When I try a naive apprach and extend my model object for User with both traints at once, I get compile errors, because the two traits have several parts (functions and types) in common without using override.

Instead I use the following approach with two model objects:

```
import net.liftweb.mapper._

/**
 * Entity class for users
 */
class User extends MegaProtoUser[User] {
  override def getSingleton = User
}

/**
 * Provides the meta model for User together with the self administration features for each user
 */
object User extends User with MetaMegaProtoUser[User] {
  override def dbTableName = "users"
}

/**
 * Again the meta model for User, but this time without self administration but with the CRUD view for the administrator
 */
object UserAdministration extends User with KeyedMetaMapper[Long, User] with ProtoUser[User] with CRUDify[Long, User] {
  override def dbTableName = User.dbTableName
}
```

This approach seems to work, but I am not sure, if I am missing some details.

1. Is there a better approach?
2. Does my approach have some unintentional effects I am missing here?
3. And finally will it still work, when I should upgrade to a newer lift version in the future?